# Can not access the staticresource from a ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, staticresource

AB.xaml MergedDictionaries A.xaml and B.xaml
CD.xaml MergedDictionaries C.xaml and D.xaml
BaseStyle.xaml MergedDictionaries AB.xaml and CD.xaml
app.xaml MergedDictionaries BaseStyle.xaml

suppose that i have a brush defined in A.xaml, and in C.xaml use the brush.

application has merged the AB.xaml first,and then CD.xaml, but the question is that **why C.xmal can not access the brush resource when runing the application using StaticResource keyword**.

Of course, DynamicResource keyword work fine. 
And if app.xaml directly Merged AB.xaml and CD.xaml, also work fine.
**so what is the different?**

Comment: It Seems like ordering issue. Have you checked that you had done that in proper order, means whenever you use the reference in resource dictionary, previous resource dictionary should already be added.

Comment: i think the ordering is correct, because i move the brush to C.xaml, and A.xaml use it.  You can have a try. The core is the different from putting AB.xaml and CD.xaml into BaseStyle.xaml.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of StaticResource within a WPF ResourceDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678893/what-is-the-scope-of-staticresource-within-a-wpf-resourcedictionary)

Answer (score 0):

finally i find the reason:
Visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/2679228/2325995

> [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx) Resources in a merged dictionary occupy a location in the resource lookup scope that is just after the scope of the main resource dictionary they are merged into.